# Python service error when importing packages

Tags: python, windows-services, pywin32

I'm trying to set up a service using pywin32 and I keep getting an error when importing packages. This is the script I'm using (I got it from another question in SO):

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

This dummy service works as intended after installing. However, when I import the necessary dependencies (say just `import numpy as np`), I can install the service just fine but it throws an error when it gets started.
[(this is the error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVlNV.png)

Just for clarification, I've tried every single solution offered in other SO posts about this (there are a ton!). I'm not using a venv; everything (script, Python installation) is on the C: drive; and I've copied the corresponding .dll files from `Python39\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32` to `Python39\Lib\site-packages\win32`. Also, just to mention, if I use debugging with `python service.py debug`, the service works just fine. I guess it could be a problem with package paths, but I've also looked at the environment variables and I don't see anything wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed my problem, this is what worked for me. Basically, for some reason some packages (like numpy) weren't installed in the main location (`Python39\Lib\`), this is likely due to the fact that whoever installed these didn't do it from an elevated cmd prompt: instead they were installed in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\...`. I didn't think this was too problematic though, as those paths were considered in the environment variables. However, when running my script as a service, the paths considered didn't take this path into account, and thus the modules weren't being found. Since there's no stdout, in order to see this I wrote the output of `sys.path` on a file, this was done inside the `main` definition.

Fixing is really simple, just uninstall all affected packages (in my case numpy, pandas and SQLAlchemy) and install them from an elevated cmd.